# Angular 2 storing bearer Token being passed as a route Param best practice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a web app (let's call it **app1**) which is redirecting a user to another app (**app2**) which leverages angular2. A Bearer Token is being passed from **app1** to **app2** as a route param which will then be stored in local storage and used across **app2**. At first I added the logic to save the token on **app2** in my login.component, but I noticed my login page as flashing for a few seconds while the user was authenticated. Then I decided to move my logic to my **LoginGuard** Class which implements **CanActivate** and looks like this:

```
canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot) {
    var myToken = route.queryParams['app1Token'] || '';

    if (myToken !== "") {
      localStorage.setItem('app2Token', myToken)

    }

    if (!localStorage.getItem('app2Token')) {
      // not logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
}
```

My question is, what is best practice when it comes to storing a token before the page loads? I've been googling around and I've seen that **canActivate** should only be used to 'Decide if a route can be activated'. I also read about **Resolve**, but I noticed that this is used to fetch data and have it available before the component loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, I went here to see what they've done in these scenarios:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

It looks like you're doing pretty much what they recommend -- use the `CanActivate` to make decisions regarding authentication, and take actions to resolve that if necessary.

The only recommendation for improvement would probably be to move your logged-in/localStorage logic into a service and then inject it.